# What if I enter JavaScript in my question text?

Tags: support

```
<script>alert("Hello")</script>
```

I wonder how Stack Overflow does it such that script code I enter as part of the question is not executed by the browser. How does SO do that?

Comment: SO sanitizes the HTML in the question text.

Comment: See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html Also if you simply View Source on the page, you will see that JavaScript is not injected into the page but styled HTML (that's how you get, among other things, syntax highlighting).

Comment: In this case because, as a code block, it's rendered as `<pre><code>`.

Comment: Isn’t this answered in the help center already? [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @jonrsharpe not sure what this comment was meant to say, but if anyone reads it as saying that HTML inside `<pre><code>` isn't parsed and `<script>` aren't executed, then be aware it is.

Answer (score 4):

It does what any sane web application does; it displays user input properly formatted as HTML content.

It would be very naive to take user input and paste it into HTML. This isn't specific to HTML. Many applications would break if you allowed arbitrary input to change the code. For this reason, developers always pass data through a formatting function that converts it into the format that can be safely accepted by that medium. In HTML, characters such as `<>'"&` are considered to be special as they are part of the markup. They are replaced in the data with HTML entities such as `&lt;`. This prevents data to be interpreted as HTML or JavaScript.

The following text:

```html
<script>alert("Hello")</script>
```

will be converted to HTML entities:

```html
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hello&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

It's worth pointing out that the text is not sanitized, but it is formatted appropriately for the given medium in which it is presented.

Comment: This is only partially correct. SE's treatment of the `<script>` tag depends on how it's entered in the Markdown source text. You're assuming it's been entered in code format using Markdown formatting. While that's commonly how code it entered, there are a variety of other ways in which the OP's HTML could have been entered (it's unclear what the OP really intends to be entering). If it was not entered in code format using Markdown formatting, the most likely thing to happen is that the `<script></script>` tag is stripped from the rendered HTML.